# Unable to run code on CLion on my Mac. I am receiving the error message "This file does not belong to any project target"

Tags: c++, clion

I am new to using CLion and am trying to build my first project. I have two source files (main.cpp and Hero.cpp) and a header for Hero.cpp. At the top of Hero.cpp there is a yellow banner that reads "This file does not belong to any project target; code insight features might not work properly." I am pretty sure there are no mistakes with regard to the syntax or logic of the program. However, when I try to run my code, I get:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o

[100%] Linking CXX executable untitled

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"Hero::GetStrength()", referenced from:

PrintHero(Hero) in main.cpp.o

"Hero::GetHitpoints()", referenced from:

PrintHero(Hero) in main.cpp.o

"Hero::GetName()", referenced from:

PrintHero(Hero) in main.cpp.o

"Hero::Hero(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> >, int, int)", referenced from:

_main in main.cpp.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

make[3]: *** [untitled] Error 1

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all] Error 2

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/rule] Error 2

make: *** [untitled] Error 2
```

Could somebody help me figure out this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you add `Hero.cpp` to a target in `CMakeLists.txt`? If not, it won't be compiled or linked into an executable. You probably want to update the default `add_executable` line to read `add_executable(YourProject main.cpp Hero.cpp)` or the likes.

Comment: Some helpful reading if you're just getting started with CMake: [An Introduction to Modern CMake](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/)

Comment: @Brian Thanks! This did the trick. Thanks also for the recommendation.